# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, netbeans-8.2

Me da este fallo al ejecutar la aplicación:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\wamp64\www\trabajocolaborativo\appcolaborativa\dao\DaoSolicitud.php:78 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\trabajocolaborativo\appcolaborativa\dao\DaoSolicitud.php(78): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\wamp64\www\trabajocolaborativo\appcolaborativa\web\controlador.php(193): DaoSolicitud->desapuntarse(NULL) #2 {main}

El caso es cuando le das un valor fijo si ejecuta todo correctamente.
Por ejemplo `$ordenSql = "DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=2";`

```
public function desapuntarse($tarea_id) {

        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $objPDO = $conexion->getPDO();
        $ordenSql = "DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=$tarea_id";
        $statement = $objPDO->prepare($ordenSql);
        $statement->bindValue(':tarea_id', $tarea_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try {
            $objPDO->beginTransaction();
            $statement->execute();
            $objPDO->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            throw ($e);
        } finally {
            $statement = NULL;
            $objPDO = NULL;
        }
    }


            case "desapuntarse":

                $dao = new DaoSolicitud();
                $tarea_id = $_REQUEST['tarea_id'];
                try {
                    $dao->Desapuntarse($tarea_id);
                    $desapuntarse = $dao->desapuntarse();
                    $_SESSION['desapuntarse'] = $desapuntarse;
                    header('Location: desplegartarea.php');
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    print ($e);
                }

            break;
```

Comment: Tienes **$dao->Desapuntarse($tarea_id);** y creo que deberia ser **$dao->desapuntarse($tarea_id);**. Luego no entiendo cuando llamas **$desapuntarse = $dao->desapuntarse();** sin parámetro

Comment: en el statement->bindValue() estas configurando el parametro id como cadena de caracteres. No sera que tendrias que ponerlo como integer?

Comment: he cambiado lo del $dao y tambien a integer y nada

Comment: Tienes mal escrita la consulta, debes ponerla así: **`DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id`**, es una consulta a preparar, debe tener por tanto un **marcador de nombre** (:tarea_id), que es lo que pasas luego en el bind, y no la variable `$tarea_id`, la cual viajará también en el bind, no en la instrucción SQL directamente.

Comment: Si lo pongo así `DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id` no me ejecuta la orden.

Comment: ¿Da algún error?  Prueba quitando o comentando esta línea: `$statement->bindValue(':tarea_id', $tarea_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);` y pasando los parámetros así: **`$statement->execute(array(':tarea_id'=>$tarea_id));`** Sea como sea, la query debe estar escrita así: `DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id` en este caso. También conviene que verifiques que efectivamente estás teniendo un valor válido en `$tarea_id`. Incluso puede que el `WHERE` no se cumpla y por eso no ejecute nada.

Comment: No no daba errores, de echo hacia todo como se espera pero no borra, y con `$statement->execute(array(':tarea_id'=>$tarea_id));` me da exactamente le mismo error

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el error que da? ¿Estás seguro de que el `WHERE` se cumple? ¿Depuraste la variable mediante `var_dump($tarea_id);` ¿Qué muestra ese `var_dump`?

Comment: Vale, encontré el error, no estaba cogiendo bien una variable. Gracias a todos por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando consultas preparadas no puedes escribir la consulta así:

<s>`DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=$tarea_id`</s>

El objetivo de las consultas preparadas es precisamente evitar la inyección de código pasando el valor de una variable como `$tarea_id` directamente a ejecución.

Por lo tanto, debes escribir la consulta usando el marcador de nombre que usas en `bindValue`:

```
DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id
```

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $objPDO = $conexion->getPDO();
    $ordenSql = "DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id";
    $statement = $objPDO->prepare($ordenSql);
    $statement->bindValue(':tarea_id', $tarea_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    try {
        $objPDO->beginTransaction();
        $statement->execute();
        $objPDO->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        throw ($e);
    } finally {
        $statement = NULL;
        $objPDO = NULL;
    }
```

También, puedes pasar los parámetros directamente en el `execute`, prescindiendo de `bindValue`:

```
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $objPDO = $conexion->getPDO();
    $ordenSql = "DELETE FROM solicitud WHERE tarea_id=:tarea_id";
    $statement = $objPDO->prepare($ordenSql);
    try {
        $objPDO->beginTransaction();
        #Creas un array con los parámetros y lo pasas en el execute
        $arrParams=array(':tarea_id', $tarea_id);
        $statement->execute($arrParams);
        $objPDO->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        throw ($e);
    } finally {
        $statement = NULL;
        $objPDO = NULL;
    }
```